# How to set Range values in a loop with alternating values

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I assume this can be written differently with a loop but I do not know how. I do not know the best Access VBA. Can anyone suggest something?

```
.Range("E4").Value = "O"
.Range("F4").Value = "U"
.Range("G4").Value = "O"
.Range("H4").Value = "U"
.Range("I4").Value = "O"
.Range("J4").Value = "U"
.Range("K4").Value = "O"
.Range("L4").Value = "U"
.Range("M4").Value = "O"
.Range("N4").Value = "U"
.Range("O4").Value = "O"
.Range("P4").Value = "U"
.Range("Q4").Value = "O"
.Range("R4").Value = "U"
.Range("S4").Value = "O"
.Range("T4").Value = "U"
.Range("U4").Value = "O"
.Range("V4").Value = "U"
.Range("W4").Value = "O"
.Range("X4").Value = "U"
.Range("Y4").Value = "O"
.Range("Z4").Value = "U"
.Range("AA4").Value = "O"
.Range("AB4").Value = "U"
.Range("AC4").Value = "O"
.Range("AD4").Value = "U"
.Range("AE4").Value = "O"
.Range("AF4").Value = "U"
.Range("AG4").Value = "O"
.Range("AH4").Value = "U"
.Range("AI4").Value = "O"
.Range("AJ4").Value = "U"
.Range("AK4").Value = "O"
.Range("AL4").Value = "U"
```

Also now and this please help

```
.Range("A5", "A6").Merge
.Range("A7", "A8").Merge
.Range("A9", "A10").Merge...

.Range("B5", "B6").Merge
.Range("B7", "B8").Merge
.Range("B9", "B10").Merge....
```

Comment: Please don't ask a second question in an edit. If you have another question -- post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a loop-free approach:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept("O U ", 17))
    Range("E4:AL4").Value = Split(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Mint works perfectly thanks and if you can send me a solution and to merge cells I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @ZdravkoLukic That really is a separate question and it should be posted as such. If you do so, you need to clarify the meaning of the ellipsis (`...`). To try to solve it yourself: note that  (assuming you are using a `With` construct that gives meaning to `.Range`) you can have the statement `.Range(.Cells(i,1),.Cells(i+1,1)).Merge` in a for-loop with step size 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't record loops with the Macro Recorder, but I think you should try that and check out the code.  You will learn a lot from that.  Well, maybe that's how you got what you got.  Anyway, I found the Macro Recorder to be helpful when I was first learning VBA.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Range("A1:D1").Merge (True)
  Range("A2:D2").Merge (True)
  Range("A3:D3").Merge (True)
End Sub
```